# Document, when compiled with error, will not compile once error is fixed when using normal \section layout

Tags: sectioning, errors

This is a problem that has been bothering me for some time, and I am really curious to know what the root cause is.

I have a LaTeX document that uses a standard \section{...}, \subsection{..}, etc... layout. However, if I ever make an error, say miss a $ somewhere, and compile, then the compiler throws an error. So far, so normal.

However, once I fix this error and recompile, I receive an error that reads:

**File ended while scanning use of @writefile  \par l.14 \begin{document}**

I've noticed (through some trial and error) that when I use \section*{...} headings throughout my document, and repeat the above process (after deleting the .aux file and other files) that I will not be served with the above error.

Does anyone have any intuition for what may be causing the conflict here?

[Link to Overleaf file with tex](https://www.overleaf.com/4652635223pkcmtftfrnzb)

Comment: Could you provide us with your full .tex code please to help you? Thank you.

Comment: I've added a link to the above question

Comment: I have seen, but, for example, I can not an username and password on Overleaf. Can you take the full code and past it into your question, please?

Comment: Most likely the aux file still carries the error. Try ignoring it and run again, or remove the aux file and compile again.

Comment: Is this locally or on overleaf? If locally, how do you stop the compilation if you get the error? (You don't get the error with section* as it doesn't try to write to the toc)